# How to adjust a JScrollPane to its contained JTree

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

here I have a swing size question:

I have a `JTree` which is contained inside a `JScrollPane` (*which is contained in a custom component which extends JXPanel from swingx, but I think that has nothing to do with this question*).

Doesn't matter how many rows the tree has, the scrollpane is always bigger (the tree is dinamic but not designed to have many rows) but what I would like is the JScrollPane to adjust to the tree initial height and then show the vertical scroll when some of the nodes are expanded.

I have tried without setting any size at all, setting tree `preferred size to null` and setting scrollpane `preferred size to null` as well but nothing changes. **I DO NOT WANT** to set the size manually... Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually just use [`setVisibleRowCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29).

Answer (score 3):

```
JTree tree = new JTree(...)
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
};
```

Comment: +1, it also solves the problem but I find better Catalina Island solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to check values of `scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()` and `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`. They should be equal to `JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` and `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`. Also tree preferred size should be set to null. With these two conditions your scrollbars should appear\disapper automatically (assuming you are using standard `JTree` and `JScrollPane`).

Comment: Thanks Kewinn, maybe I did not may myself clear enough... the problem is not in the scrollbars but in the size of the viewport. I would like it to adjust to its content (the tree) initial size but now it is much bigger

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter this issue and this is the best way to do it without specifying a size from your JTree nor your JScrollpane is to set **JTree** to **setViewportView()** method of **JScrollpane**.

```
JScrollPane scrollTree = new JScrollPane(yourJTree);
scrollTree.setViewportView(yourJTree);
```

I think this is the best way to do it since you don't need to specify any size of Component or get a number of rows to adjust the scrollpane.